# Loading print composer template and nothing turns up

Tags: qgis, print-composer, save

I am with Qgis 2.14.1 Essen, I had stored several templates on print composer, but today trying to load again those templates and the working area turns up totally blank, and the computer seems struggling to do anything in to there (check the link)

[My screen when I am trying to load a save print composer template](http://prntscr.com/axt8o6)

My question is, can I recover my info and start working again with this print composer?

To clarify: I try to use the print composer with and without my projects, just in a blank new file, but still the same problem.